# Flutter Show 1 progress Indicator for SingleChildScrollView with different widgets

Tags: flutter

I have ecommerce App in which I am loading multiple widgets which uses their own Future to build it. I have 6 widgets in SingleChildScrollView. Issue is I see 6 CircularProgressIndicator which looks very bad. is there any way to check _isLoading and show only 1 CircularProgressIndicator for full Page while widgets are builiding in background.

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  bool _isLoading = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _isLoading
          ? Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()))
          : SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  CarouselSliderList(),
                  Banner1Slot(),
                  TopCategoriesList(),
                  HotProducts(),
                  TopCategoriesIconList(),
                  AllProduct(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

Example of 1 widget in SingleChildScrollView in HomeScreen.

```
class Banner1Slot extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TopCategoriesListState createState() => _TopCategoriesListState();
}

class _TopCategoriesListState extends State<Banner1Slot> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Banner1>>(
      future: getBanner1(http.Client()),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
        return snapshot.hasData
            ? Banner1Image(
                banner1: snapshot.data,
              )
            : Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.black26,
                ),
              );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The way you have constructed the Widget to pass to the body parameter, looks like it should show only 1 CircularProgressIndicator, unless you have put a CircularProgressIndicator in each of the children of the Column too. Have you?

Comment: If i set _isLoading = true, it keeps loading and doesn't show screen. and yes each widget has CircularProgressIndicator.

Comment: If you are using a `StatefulWidget`, did you make sure you are calling `setState()` when you set `_isLoading = true` ?

Comment: No. and I have no Idea how to implement `setState()` for `_isLoading = true`

Comment: I see. Looks like you need to share other relevant parts of your code for anyone to be able to help you further with this.

Comment: I have made edits to question with code for `HomeScreen` and 1 widget part of `SingleChildScrollView()`

Comment: Do you want to show the single circular progress indicator until every child is done with loading?

Comment: @ZeRj Yes. Current HomeScreen UI looks bad as it shows 6 progress indicators